# What are the criteria for determining if a language can be parsed using recursive descent parsing?

Tags: parsing, grammar, recursive-descent

How do i know if a language can be parsed by recursive descent parsing?

For example, how would i go about determining whether this language can be parsed in that manner:

Language = { s^p r^q | p > q }?

I have tried reading about the concept but it doesn't click.

Comment: "Recursive descent" isn't a formally defined parsing model, it's a loosely defined implementation technique, so whether a language can be parsed by recursive descent isn't well-defined.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to know whether it is possible for the following:
A = { x^n y^n | n <= k }
B = { x^n y^k | n > k }
C = { x^k y^n | k > n }
D = { x^n y^n r^n | n <= k }
E = { x^n y^n r^n | n >= k }
where there are n occurences of x,y,r and k is unknown (but fixed).

Thank you very much

Comment: I don't think you get my point. I'm saying that the term "recursive descent parser" is too imprecise for there to be a useful answer to your question.